# How to pass XML to stored procedure from Entity Framework in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have written a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014, and I am using Entity Framework 6 to call that stored procedure.

I need to pass two xml(s) into the stored procedure, is it possible to pass them from Entity Framework?

My stored procedure taking input:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddOrUpdateUserPortfolio]
    @UserId nvarchar(128),
    @Name nvarchar,
    @Country int,
    @State int,
    @City int,
    @Phone nvarchar,
    @About nvarchar,
    @Professions xml,
    @ArtCategories xml
AS
BEGIN
```

Is there any way to pass xml, or else I need to make call for each item ?

Comment: Did you try to pass XDocument as a parametere to your function in EF?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use! Right now, your parameters `@Name`, `@Phone`, `@About` are **exactly 1 character long** since you didn't provide a length ....

Comment: Thanks for telling me, I solved it by passing xml string.